AG- Grid sort column using ValueFormatter or valueGetter
I have read and tried using some the topics on here when it comes to my issue, but I still can't seem to get something to work. The backend is a number and I'm using the ValueGetter and/or ValueFormatter to display a text. The issue as many on this site is that the column wont sort.
here's a sample my code.
the ts file part first
// { headerName: 'Region',
    //   valueGetter: this.regionNameFormater,
    // // valueFormatter: this.regionNameFormater,
    //  filterParams:{
    //    valueGetter:(params:any)=> this.regionNameFormater(params)
    //    },
    //     comparator:filterParams2,

    //   sortable: true
    // },
    { headerName: 'Region',
      valueFormatter: this.regionNameFormater,
      filterParams:{
        valueGetter:(params:any)=> this.regionNameFormater(params)
        },
        comparator:filterParams2,

      sortable: true
    },
    // { headerName: 'Region',
    //   valueGetter: (p)=> p.data.region_code,
    //   filterParams: {
    //     valueFormatter: (params:any)=> this.regionNameFormater(params)
    //   },
    //  // valueFormatter: this.regionNameFormater,
    // //  filterParams:{
    //   //  valueGetter:(params:any)=> this.regionNameFormater(params)
    //   //  },
    //     comparator:filterParams2,

    //   sortable: true
    // },
public regionNameFormater(params:any){

    let region = params.data.region_code

    switch(region){
      case(1):
        return 'Boston';
        break;
      case(3):
        return 'Philadelphia';
        break;
      case(4):
        return 'Atlanta';
        break;
      case(5):
        return 'Chicago';
        break;
      case(6):
        return 'Dallas';
        break;
      case(8):
        return 'San Francisco';
        break;
      case(9):
        return 'National';
        break;
      case(0):
        return '';
      default:
        return region;
        break;
    }

  }
  function filterParams2 (value1:any,value2:any) {
    if (value1 === null && value2 === null) {
    return 0;
   }
   if (value1 === null) {
    return -1;
   }
   if (value2 === null) {
    return 1;
   }
   return value1 - value2;
   }
 public defaultColDef: ColDef ={
    sortable: true,
    filter: true,
    wrapHeaderText: true,
    autoHeaderHeight:true,
    wrapText : true,
    autoHeight: true,
    resizable: true,

  
    
  }
////////////////////HTML///////
       <ag-grid-angular
        #allAssignments
        style="width: auto; height: 800px;"
        class="ag-theme-alpine  mx-auto"
        (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" 
        [columnDefs]= "colDefs"
        [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
        [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
        [rowData]="dataReviews"
        (rowClicked)="getSelectedRowData($event)"
        
        ></ag-grid-angular>
////////////////////////////////

    

I have tried some of the solutions on here like I said but maybe I missed something and my code is what is stopping it from sorting. let me know if I should format it differently
thanks
I have try to use a sorting function as some of the solutions on here said to do. But it doesn't sort
